# Alternative ways to include sub-modules into classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

Suppose we have this code:

```
module A
  def n1
    puts 'n1'
  end

  module AA
    def n2
      puts 'n2'
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

B.new.n1
B.new.n2
```

The last line will not work unless I do something like include A:AA, or maybe this:

```
def self.included(base)
    base.include AA
 end
```

but are there any other (more convenient) ways to include or reference sub-modules without explicitly including them with :: or inside self.included?

Comment: If you want to include a module, you need to use `include`. I don't understand, what more you are looking for.

Comment: What is the purpose of defining `n2` within `AA`? Encapsuling `n2` within `AA` and trying to access it without explicit mentioning of `AA` seem contradictory to one another.

Comment: Has the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

To add methods `n1` and `n2` in `class B`, you could:

- add `include A::AA` to the class definition or
- add `include AA` in the `module A` definition, ***after*** the `module AA` definition,

but it makes more sense to:

- move the `module AA` definition out of the `module A` definition and add `include AA` to the class definition, or
- define `module AA` ***before*** defining `module A` and add `include AA` to the `module A` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine the `Module` class' `:include` method as below, and you be able to include modules recursive:

```
class Module
   alias :include_orig :include

   def include mod, options = {}
      mod.constants.each do| const |
         c = A.const_get const
         self.include c, options if c.is_a? Module
      end if options[ :recursive ]

      self.send :include_orig, mod
   end
end
```

Then call:

```
class B
   include A, :recursive => true
end

B.new.n1
B.new.n2

# n1
# n2
```